# Stored Map Like Google Maps or OpenLayers

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, openlayers

Is Their anything like stored maps from where I can get Latitude/Longitude from address and vice versa. Like a database file or something else other than web based services so that I will not have to be connected over Internet while calculating address from Latitude/Longitude and Counter-wise.
Thank You

**EDIT** : Just to be clear. We use Google API's to find out Routes between two Geo-Locations I need the Same Feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nominatim ? [1] It’s one of the source for the OSM home page.
Source code is on github [2].

1: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim
2: https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim

**EDIT**: I didn’t understand correctly. You can checkout OSRM : http://project-osrm.org/

Comment: No Not like this. I mean I cant get the Route between Two Geo-locations using this. can I  ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check out [Navit](http://www.navit-project.org/) it is an open source offline routing and navigation application. They have a wiki over [here](http://wiki.navit-project.org/index.php/Main_Page) which also explains a bit about [routing](http://wiki.navit-project.org/index.php/Routing).

I have not tried the application, but one of the features mentioned in the wiki is "adress and POI search".

There are several [means of contact](http://wiki.navit-project.org/index.php/Contacts) mentioned in their wiki as well, if you want to ask them about how they did.

You might also want to check out this list to find other interesting apps that provide offline map storage, routing and/or offline address search http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software/Desktop

This looks interesting as well: [OSM Automated Navigation Directions](http://code.google.com/p/osmand/).